# Best way in SQL to eliminate result rows with the same $ value but a day apart

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table that looks like the following

| Region | Location | $ Amount | Date | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Location1 | 500 | 2021-01-01 | UserA |
| 1 | Location1 | -500 | 2021-01-02 | UserA |
| 2 | Location2 | 700 | 2021-01-03 | UserB |

I want to find and remove the rows where the columns all match except the date is 1 day off and the $ amounts are opposite. In this example I would want to remove rows 1 and 2 because they are opposite $ amounts and only one day off.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

This does what you describe:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.region = t.region and
                        t2.location = t.location and
                        t2.name = t.name and
                        t2.amount = - t.amount and
                        t2.date in (t.date - 1, t.date + 1)
                 );
```

However, you might want to think about how you phrased the problem.  What happens if you have 100/-100/100?  The logic you describe (and the above query) will remove all three rows.  That might be what you intend.  If it is not, though, you should ask a *new* question.

Note:  The above removes the rows from a result set.  It is easy to modify this for a `delete`.

Comment: Thank you for the input. You bring up a good point, I don't think it should be possible with my data but I'll look into it to be sure

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_name x
  WHERE  x.region = t.region
  AND    x.location = t.location
  AND    x.amount = -t.amount
  AND    x."DATE" IN (t."DATE" - 1, t."DATE" + 1)
  AND    x.name = t.name 
)
```

*Note: `DATE` is a keyword and you cannot use it for a column name unless you use a quoted identifier.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=963eab033d485705cfc32f86596f5ae4)*